# Array range complement

Tags: arrays, julia

Is there a way to overwrite `[]` to have complement of range in array?

```
julia> a=[1:8...]
8-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8

julia> a[-1] == a[2:8]
julia> a[-(1:3)] == a[4:8]
julia> a[-end] == a[1:7]
```

Comment: This would be terribly misleading. Even in languages supporting negative indices (e.g. python), these result in an _indexing_ operation, not a _slice_. Why would you want to create such confusion in the first place?

Comment: "Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn’t stop to think if they should."  ~ Jurassic Park

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't looked into the internals of indexing before, but at a first glance, the following might work without breaking too much:

```julia
immutable Not{T}
    idx::T
end    

if :to_indices in names(Base)
    # 0.6
    import Base: to_indices, uncolon, tail, _maybetail

    @inline to_indices(A, inds, I::Tuple{Not, Vararg{Any}}) =
       (setdiff(uncolon(inds, (:, tail(I)...)), I[1].idx), to_indices(A, _maybetail(inds), tail(I))...)       
else
    # 0.5
    import Base: getindex, _getindex

    not_index(a::AbstractArray, I, i::Int) = I
    not_index(a::AbstractArray, I::Not, i::Int) = setdiff(indices(a, i), I.idx)

    getindex(a::AbstractArray, I::Not) = getindex(a, setdiff(linearindices(a), I.idx))
    _getindex(::Base.LinearIndexing, a::AbstractArray, I::Vararg{Union{Real, AbstractArray, Colon, Not}}) = 
        Base._getindex(Base.linearindexing(a), a, (not_index(a, idx, i) for (i,idx) in enumerate(I))...)
end
```

For example:

```julia
julia> a = reshape(1:9, (3, 3))
3×3 Base.ReshapedArray{Int64,2,UnitRange{Int64},Tuple{}}:
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9

julia> a[Not(2:8)]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
1
9

julia> a[Not(1:2), :]
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
3  6  9


julia> a[Not(end), end]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
7
8
```

I didn't care for performance and also did no extensive testing, so things can certainly be improved.

**Edit:**

I replaced the code for 0.6 with Matt B. version from his github comment linked in the comments.

Thanks to his great design of the array indexing implementation for 0.6, only a single function needs to be extended to get complement indexing for `getindex`, `setindex` and `view`, e.g.,

```julia
julia> view(a, Not(2:8))
2-element SubArray{Int64,1,UnitRange{Int64},Tuple{Array{Int64,1}},false}:
1
9

# collect because ranges are immutable
julia> b = collect(a); b[Not(2), Not(2)] = 10; b
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
10  4  10
 2  5   8
10  6  10
```

Comment: This is the right way forward! I explicitly designed the internals to allow for this sort of index type on 0.6.  You shouldn't even need the `getindex` definition.  Ref. https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/19730#issuecomment-270012805.

Comment: @MattB. Great work! It was indeed much clearer what to do on 0.6 than on 0.5. The only thing I missed was the `uncolon` function. That's why I kept the additional `getindex` method for linear indexing that I needed for 0.5. May I update my answer with your code from your github comment?

Comment: Thanks! Go for it. The whole idea behind this interface was to enable others to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Directly overwriting `[]`(i.e. `getindex`) is prone to break many indexing-related things in Base, but we can write an array wrapper to work around it. We only need to define the following three methods to get your specific test cases passed:

```julia
immutable ComplementVector{T} <: AbstractArray{T,1}
    data::Vector{T}
end
Base.size(A:: ComplementVector) = size(A.data)
Base.getindex(A:: ComplementVector, i::Integer) = i > 0 ? A.data[i] : A.data[setdiff(1:end, (-i))]
Base.getindex(A:: ComplementVector, I::StepRange) = all(x->x>0, I) ? A.data[I] : A.data[setdiff(1:end, -I)]

julia> a = ComplementVector([1:8...])

julia> a[-1] == a[2:8]
true

julia> a[-(1:3)] == a[4:8]
true

julia> a[-end] == a[1:7]
true
```

If you would like to extend `ComplementVector` further more, please read the doc about [`Interfaces`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/interfaces.html#Interfaces-1).

### Update:

For safety sake, we'd better not extend `AbstractArray` as @Fengyang Wang suggested in the comment blow:

```julia
immutable ComplementVector{T}
    data::Vector{T}
end
Base.endof(A::ComplementVector) = length(A.data)
Base.getindex(A::ComplementVector, i::Integer) = i > 0 ? A.data[i] : A.data[setdiff(1:end, (-i))]
Base.getindex(A::ComplementVector, I::OrdinalRange) = all(x->x>0, I) ? A.data[I] : A.data[setdiff(1:end, -I)]
```

Comment: This also seems like it is prone to trouble because it violates the assumptions made by `AbstractArray`. It's probably better to define a new type for indexing, say `ComplementCartesianRange`, instead of a new type to be indexed.

Comment: @FengyangWang I thought the same, but it seems OP was looking for a way to overwrite `getindex` in order to get a "syntax sugar"(e.g. `a[-1]`<=>`a[2:end]`).  IMHO, a function is fair enough for this kind of usage.

Comment: perhaps it should not extend `AbstractArray` then? that would seem safer.

Comment: Thanks for directly answer my question. Howerver I accepted tim's answer because it is a more proper way and it supports slicing.