# Julia's Negative/Complement Indexing like R

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

Is there a functionality in Julia that's similar to R's negative indexing? In R, the code would be similar to:

```
x = 1:10
inds = c(1, 5, 7)
x[-inds]

[1]  2  3  4  6  8  9 10
```

I've found this to be extremely useful in numerous situations, especially for things such as sampling indices to create a testing/training set, but also for subindexing an array to exclude certain rows. So I am hoping there's something simple in Julia that can do the same.

Comment: `x[setdiff(1:10, inds)]` works. Not sure if there is anything simpler, which is why I've made this a comment.

Comment: OP, it is worth checking out the package Bill links below too. The package maintainer is a prolific dev in the Julia community, so it is likely to be implemented using efficient methods and to just work for many different input index types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array range complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382210/array-range-complement)

Comment: @ColinTBowers Neat, simple idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to @Colin T Bower's answer and also only uses base Julia.  Afraid it is not as elegant as your R example.

```
julia> minus(indx, x) = setdiff(1:length(x), indx)
minus (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = collect(1:10)
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10

julia> inds = [1, 5, 7]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 5
 7

julia> x[minus(inds, x)]
7-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  3
  4
  6
  8
  9
 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a feature of the base language, but see for example the package here: https://github.com/mbauman/InvertedIndices.jl

Comment: See also discussion about adding this to Julia itself here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1032