# Julia: how to deselect rows in a matrix when the row numbers are stored in an array

Tags: julia

I want to remove rows from a matrix `A`.

The row numbers I want to remove are stored in an array `B`.

**For example**:

`B=[1,2,3]` means that I want to remove rows 1, 2, and 3 from matrix `A`. How can I do that in the Julia Language?

Comment: I was going to vote-to-close as a duplicate of [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378061/julias-negative-complement-indexing-like-r), but on second thought, perhaps because OP is asking about matrices, not vectors, the question is sufficiently different to not be a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, InvertedIndices.jl makes this just A[Not(B), :] But you guys like base Julia answers, right?

Comment: @ColinTBowers If you would want to delete rows (i.e. elements) from a vector you could simply do `deleteat!(vec, inds)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to install any additional packages, then the current neatest solution I am aware of is:

```
x = randn(5, 2)
inds_to_remove = [1,3,4]
x[setdiff(1:size(x,1), inds_to_remove), :]
```

What this question really boils down to is how to invert a set of indices, which has already been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378061/julias-negative-complement-indexing-like-r). From the linked question, note that there is also a package for this, [InvertedIndices](https://github.com/mbauman/InvertedIndices.jl), which will work for collections of arbitrary dimension.

It is also worth noting that if you only want to remove a single row, then:

```
x[1:end .!= i, :]
```

is a fast, neat solution.

Comment: This is neat(!) but unfortunately isn't performant. See my benchmark below.

Comment: @crstnbr See my counter-comment on your benchmark :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another much faster (but less neat) possibility is

```
vcat(deleteat!([A[r,:]' for r in 1:size(A, 1)], inds)...)
```

i.e. extract the rows as a vector, delete the relevant rows, transform back to matrix shape.

**Example:**

```
julia> A = randn(5, 2)
5×2 Array{Float64,2}:
  0.0204771   0.641602
 -0.51661     0.0314303
 -0.0667214  -1.61672
 -0.303866    2.0537
 -1.31845    -1.44462

julia>     inds = [1,3,4]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 3
 4

julia>     vcat(deleteat!([A[r,:]' for r in 1:size(A, 1)], inds)...)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.51661   0.0314303
 -1.31845  -1.44462
```

Note that the resulting matrix is a copy and `A` hasn't been modified, just like in @ColinTBowers answer.

**Benchmark:**

```
julia> @btime vcat(deleteat!([$(A)[r,:]' for r in 1:size($A, 1)], $inds)...);
  405.335 ns (17 allocations: 912 bytes)

julia> @btime $(A)[setdiff(1:size($A,1), 1:3), :]; # @ColinTBowers answer
  5.049 μs (58 allocations: 2.16 KiB)
```

In the latter, `setdiff` seems to be a big bottleneck:

```
julia> @btime setdiff(1:size($A,1), $inds)
  3.253 μs (40 allocations: 1.59 KiB)
```

**Manual implementation**

Speedwise, all of the above should be compared to a fast manual implementation. Something along the lines of

```
rmrows(A, inds) = begin
  rows, cols = size(A)
  out = similar(A, rows-length(inds), cols)
  for c in 1:cols
    i = 1
    for r in 1:rows
      if !(r in inds)
         @inbounds out[i,c] = A[r,c]
         i+=1
      end
    end
  end
  out
end
```

which leads to

```
julia> @btime rmrows($A, $inds);
  60.581 ns (1 allocation: 112 bytes)
```

**Update1: manual implementation**

**Update2: faster manual implementation**

Comment: I think you could go column-wise in your manual implementation and obtain a faster solution especially for arrays of larger sizes. There might be some other optimizations (if `inds` is larger then half the size of the matrix, then inverting it first to get faster search in your `if` inside your for loop, maybe), as well. So considering the package developers (probably) do this kind of optimizations themselves, going for the package is usually the best bet.

Comment: @hckr Agreed. I just wanted to get a rough estimate for a manual implementation.

Comment: Great answer! However, be aware that for this problem, algorithm efficiency is highly dependent on the size of the inputs. On my machine, the `setdiff` approach is easily dominant when you really scale the problem up, e.g. try 10000 rows, 500 columns, and 500 rows to remove.